# Context error while testing RESTful API URL in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Dear community and forum,

I am in charge of developing RESTful API URLs for a website project. However, when it comes to testing I have got that error:

```
self = HyperlinkedIdentityField('api:request')
value = <ResourceRequest: JoKLLwwKqxrkrwWmcjOWzIscGzpsbgWJqRAOZabnwxQpiEDRfifeZhvzpRRp...ewyOFcaQVhchYNVIhUoiWBzKMrFYvYQBMNRZsLFfOZSjclHUXwyXZQHxjMtbHvWefMIlyZqvTvXqiu>

 def to_representation(self, value):
    assert 'request' in self.context, (
        "`%s` requires the request in the serializer"
        " context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating "
           "the serializer." % self.__class__.__name__
    )
E       AssertionError: `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py:351: AssertionError
```

The serialiser is (sorry for the ugly code so far):

```
class ResourceRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # context = self.kwargs.get('context', None)
    # request = kwargs['context']['request']
    # print(kwargs)
    view_name = 'api:request'
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name)
    # print(self)
    # url = URLField(view_name=view_name, read_only=True, many=True)
    # url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    support_level = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    originator = BriefUCLProfileSerializer(source='originator.ucl_profile')
    sponsor = BriefUCLProfileSerializer()
    versioned_dependencies = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    types_of_work = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    previous = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    status_history = RequestStatusChangeSerializer(many=True)
```

For the test:

```
# Change the status through a POST request
response = self.app.post(
    reverse(
        'api:request',
        args=[request1.pk],
    ),
    params={
        'context': request1,
        'format': 'json',
        'status': ResourceRequest.STATUS_APPROVED,
    },
    # context=request1,
    headers=self.auth_headers,
)
```

I am still wondering if the context has to be passed from within the serialiser or from the test.

Here is the view too:

```
class ResourceRequestAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
"""Retrieve an individual resource request by pk and optionally update status"""
serializer_class = ResourceRequestSerializer
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication)

def get_object(self):
    try:
        return ResourceRequest.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    except ResourceRequest.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    resource_request = self.get_object()
    status = request.data['status']
    if status != ResourceRequest.STATUS_SUBMITTED:
        # Change the status
        resource_request.set_status(status,
                                    request.user)
        # And send emails
        request_url = request.build_absolute_uri(
            reverse('api:request', args=[resource_request.pk])
        )
        send_emails(resource_request,
                    request_url=request_url,
        )
    serializer = ResourceRequestSerializer(resource_request)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any help greatly appreciated !

Thank you

Roland

Comment: Show us the code for your view/viewset too; that's the place that should set the context.

Comment: @AKX Here is the view. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so with that viewset in hand, you'll have to initialize the serializer with the context:

```
serializer = ResourceRequestSerializer(
   resource_request,
   context=self.get_serializer_context(),
)
```

`get_serializer_context()` is provided by default by DRF viewsets.

Comment: thank you, that worked ! For the sake of argument, anytime there is a GET/POST request, the context has to be passed from the view to the serialiser ?

Comment: If the serializer requires context for something, sure.

Comment: you can use the generic function provided: `self.get_serializer()` (just like the `mixins` use) as well - that function already calls the `self.get_serializer_context()` and adds it to the serializer being instantiated

Comment: @henriquesalvaro OK ! That's good to know thanks :) However, how would you specify a `serializer` of choice ? In other words, it looks to me that the `self.get_serializer()` returns a generic one ?

Comment: it returns the serializer defined in your class through the `serializer_class` variable.
you can check it [here](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/GenericViewSet.html#get_serializer) and [here](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/GenericViewSet.html#get_serializer_class)

Comment: Cool ! Thanks a million.